# How to conveniently plot a list of various transformed functions y=a|f(b|x+c|)|+d of a piecewisely-defined fundamental function y=f(x)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

I have a fundamental function `y=f(x)` given piecewisely as follows.

[image]
[image]

I want to plot a list of its transformed functions (such as `y=af(bx+c)+d`, `y=a|f(b|x+c|)|+d`) as conveniently as using Mathematica.

For comparison, let me show the Mathematica code first as follows.

```
ClearAll[F, family, plots];
F[x_] := 0 /; x < -6;
F[x_] := (x + 4)^2/4 - 1 /; -6 <= x < -2;
F[x_] := -(x + 1)^2 + 1 /; -2 <= x < 0;
F[x_] := -x /; 0 <= x < 2;
F[x_] := x - 4 /; 2 <= x < 6;
F[x_] := 2 /; x >= 6;
family = {F[x]
   , F[2 x]
   , 2 F[x]
   , F[x - 2]
   , F[x] - 2
   , 2 F[2 x + 1] - 1
   , F[Abs[x]]
   , F[-Abs[x]]
   , Abs@F[x]
   , -Abs@F[x]
   , -Abs@F[Abs[x]]
   , -Abs@F[-Abs[x]]
   };
plots = Plot[#, {x, -7, 7}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions", 
     ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All] & /@ family;
Partition[plots, 2] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

I attempted to replicate the code in PSTricks but it seems to be too cumbersome because for each `pspicture`, I have to do  tedious and error-prone extra jobs

- Adjusting the first 2 parameters of `psplot`
- Calling `psplot` 6 times, each call uses different domain and function.
- Rearranging the order of `\psplot` calls in `\pscustom`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\Fa#1{0}                        % x < -6
\def\Fb#1{((#1)+4)^2/4-1}           % -6 <= x < -2
\def\Fc#1{-((#1)+1)^2+1}            % -2 <= x < 0
\def\Fd#1{-(#1)}                    % 0 <= x < 2
\def\Fe#1{(#1)-4}                   % 2 <= x < 6
\def\Ff#1{2}                        % x >= 6

\begin{document}
% plotting y=f(x)
\pspicture(-8,-4)(8.5,4.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-8,-4)(8,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,algebraic]
    {
        \psplot{-8}{-6}{\Fa{x}}
        \psplot{-6}{-2}{\Fb{x}}
        \psplot{-2}{0}{\Fc{x}}
        \psplot{0}{2}{\Fd{x}}
        \psplot{2}{6}{\Fe{x}}
        \psplot{6}{8}{\Ff{x}}
    }
\endpspicture
% plotting y=f(2x)
\pspicture(-8,-4)(8.5,4.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-8,-4)(8,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,algebraic]
    {
        \psplot{-8}{-3}{\Fa{2*x}}
        \psplot{-3}{-1}{\Fb{2*x}}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{\Fc{2*x}}
        \psplot{0}{1}{\Fd{2*x}}
        \psplot{1}{3}{\Fe{2*x}}
        \psplot{3}{8}{\Ff{2*x}}
    }
\endpspicture
% plotting y=f(-x)
\pspicture(-8,-4)(8.5,4.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-8,-4)(8,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,algebraic]
    {
        \psplot{-8}{-6}{\Ff{-x}}
        \psplot{-6}{-2}{\Fe{-x}}
        \psplot{-2}{0}{\Fd{-x}}
        \psplot{0}{2}{\Fc{-x}}
        \psplot{2}{6}{\Fb{-x}}
        \psplot{6}{8}{\Fa{-x}}
    }
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

## Question

I want to

- only create a single function `\def\F#1{}` instead of six functions `\Fa`,..., `\Ff`.
- only call a single `\psplot` in each `pspicture`, for example, `\psplot{-8}{8}{-2*abs(\F{-abs(x-3)})-2}`.

How to  realize these requirement in PSTricks, or its friends?

Comment: +1 for pstricks code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage               {pst-plot}

\def\function{  
  u -6 lt { 0 }
    { u -2 lt { u 4 add dup mul 4 div 1 sub }
      { u 0 lt { u 1 add dup mul neg 1 add }
        { u 2 lt { u neg }
          { u 6 lt { u 4 sub }
            { 2 } ifelse
          } ifelse
        } ifelse
      } ifelse
    } ifelse
}     
  
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,-3)(8,3.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-8,-3)(8,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
  \psset{linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=1000}%
  \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-8}{8}{ x /u ED \function }
  \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{-8}{8}{ x /u ED \function\space abs }
  \psplot[linecolor=green]{-8}{8}{ x 1 add abs /u ED \function\space 0.1 add }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As you include `tikz-pgf` in the tags I offer you a pgfplots solution. I'm not sure if it is a friend of PSTrikcs :->

You can declare your piecewise function, and then call it in the `\addplot`s commands, alone or combined (composed) with other functions.

A starting point could be:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage               {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset              {compat=1.17}

\tikzset{declare function={
    func(\x) =  (\x<-6) * 0                     + % not really necessary
     and(\x>=-6, \x<-2) * ((\x+4)*(\x+4)/4 - 1) +
     and(\x>=-2, \x< 0) * (-(\x+1)*(\x+1) + 1)  +
     and(\x>= 0, \x< 2) * (-\x)                 +
     and(\x>= 2, \x< 6) * (\x-4)                +
                (\x>=6) * 2;
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-8, xmax=8,
    ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    domain=-8:8,
    samples=161, % you'll probably must play with the number of samples (see edit)
    xtick={-8,-6,...,8},
    ytick={-4,...,4},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    \addplot [thick,blue]       plot (\x,{func(\x)});
    \addplot [thick,red,dashed] plot (\x,{abs(func(\x))});
    \addplot [thick,magenta]    plot (\x,{func(abs(\x+1))+0.1});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

Of course, you can define several `axis` environments to draw each function separately as shown in your picture.

**Edit:** two changes:

1. I shifted the third function on the y-axis for a better visualization.
2. I changed the number of samples, and it looks better with less samples if we choose them wisely. As the points where the pieces of the functions change are -8,-6,-3,-1,0,1,2,4,5,6,8 (counting the three functions) we need a set of samples that contains all those points. So any multiple of 16 plus 1 `(16n+1)` will be better than other numbers. So 160+1 better than 200+1 (value before the edit).

Comment: @WhoSaveMeSaveEntireWorld, of course, you are right. Edited!

Comment: Very clever use of the logic gates into a function definition +1

Comment: Thanks @SebGlav, I almost certainly learned how to do it in a post on this site.

Answer (score 4):

My try with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) from Herbert's pstricks code.

```
import graph;
unitsize(1cm);

real f(real x) {
  return (x<-6) ? 0 : 
        (x<-2) ? (x+4)^2/4-1 :
        (x<0) ? -(x+1)^2+1 :
        (x<2) ? -x :
        (x<6) ? x-4 : 2;
}
real g(real x){ return abs(f(x)); } // |f(x)|
real h(real x){ return -3*abs(f(-2*abs(x+1)))-1; } // y=-3|f(-2|x+1|)|-1

draw(graph(f,-8,8,1000),red+1bp);
draw(graph(g,-8,8,1000),0.7bp+blue+dashed);
draw(graph(h,-8,8,1000),green+0.7bp);

xaxis(-8,8,Ticks(Step=1,Size=3,endlabel=false,end=false),Arrow);
label("$x$",(8,0),dir(-90));
yaxis(-3,3,Ticks(Step=1,Size=3,endlabel=false,end=false),Arrow);
label("$y$",(0,3),dir(0));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but since the question is tagged [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and no one else has offered an answer, here is an effort from me.

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef f(expr x) = 
    if     x < -6: 0
    elseif x < -2: ((x+4)**2)/4 - 1
    elseif x <  0: 1 - (x+1)**2
    elseif x <  2: -x
    elseif x <  6: x - 4
    else: 2 fi enddef;

string t[];
vardef A(expr x) = f(x) enddef;              t1 = "$f(x)$";
vardef B(expr x) = f(2x) enddef;             t2 = "$f(2x)$";
vardef C(expr x) = 2f(x) enddef;             t3 = "$2f(x)$";
vardef D(expr x) = f(x-2) enddef;            t4 = "$f(x-2)$";
vardef E(expr x) = f(x)-2 enddef;            t5 = "$f(x)-2$";
vardef F(expr x) = 2f(2x+1)-1 enddef;        t6 = "$2f(2x+1)-1)$";
vardef G(expr x) = f(abs(x)) enddef;         t7 = "$f(|x|)$";
vardef H(expr x) = f(-abs(x)) enddef;        t8 = "$f(-|x|)$";
vardef I(expr x) = abs(f(x)) enddef;         t9 = "$|f(x)|$";
vardef J(expr x) = -abs(f(x)) enddef;        t10 = "$-|f(x)|$";
vardef K(expr x) = -abs(f(abs(x))) enddef;   t11 = "$-|f(|x|)|$";
vardef L(expr x) = -abs(f(-abs(x))) enddef;  t12 = "$-|f(-|x|)|$";

vardef plot@#(expr a, s, b) = 
    (a, @#(a)) for x=a+s step s until b: -- (x, @#(x)) endfor
enddef;

picture p[];
numeric i; i = 0;
forsuffixes $=A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L:
    p[incr i] = image(
        drawarrow (left--right) scaled 160 withcolor 7/8;
        drawarrow (down--up) scaled 100 withcolor 7/8;
        draw plot $ (-7, 1/16, 7) scaled 20 withcolor 1/2 red;
        label.rt(t[i], (-160, 12));
    ); 
endfor

beginfig(1);
for i=2 step 2 until infinity:
    exitif not known p[i];
    picture r; 
    r = image(label.lft(p[i-1], 10 left); label.rt(p[i], 10 right));
    label.bot(r, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture);
endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Herbert's answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\F{  
    u -6 lt { 0 }{ 
    u -2 lt { ((u+4)^2/4-1) I2P }{ 
    u 0 lt  { (-(u+1)^2+1) I2P }{ 
    u 2 lt  { (-u) I2P }{   
    u 6 lt  { (u-4) I2P }{ 2 }  ifelse } 
                                ifelse } 
                                ifelse } 
                                ifelse } 
                                ifelse }     
  

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}%
\foreach \f/\l in 
{
    {x 2 mul /u ED \F}/{y=f(2x)},
    {x 2 mul 3 div /u ED \F}/{y=f(\tfrac{2x}{3})},
    {x  /u ED \F\space 2 mul}/{y=2f(x)},
    {x neg /u ED \F}/{y=f(-x)},
    {x  /u ED \F\space neg}/{y=-f(x)},
    {x 1 sub /u ED \F}/{y=f(x-1)},
    {x  /u ED \F\space 1 add}/{y=f(x)+1},
    {x 2 exp /u ED \F}/{y=f(x^2)},
    {x 2 exp neg /u ED \F}/{y=f(-x^2)},
    {x /u ED \F\space abs}/{y=|f(x)|},
    {x abs /u ED \F}/{y=f(|x|)},
    {x abs /u ED \F\space abs}/{y=|f(|x|)|},
    {x abs neg /u ED \F}/{y=f(-|x|)},
    {x /u ED \F\space abs neg}/{y=-|f(x)|},
    {x abs neg /u ED \F\space abs neg}/{y=-|f(-|x|)|},
    {x 1 sub abs 2 mul /u ED \F\space abs -3 mul 4 add}/{y=-3|f(2|x-1|)|+4},
    { (-2*abs(x+1)) I2P /u ED \F\space abs -3 mul 4 add}/{y=-3|f(-2|x+1|)|+4}
}
{%
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-6)(10.5,6.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-10,-6)(10,6)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
  \psset{plotpoints=1601,linejoin=1,strokeopacity=0.5}%
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=3pt]{-10}{10}{x /u ED \F}
    \rput(-4,6){\textcolor{red!50}{$y=f(x)$}}
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{-10}{10}{\f}
    \rput(4,6){\textcolor{blue!50}{$\l$}}   
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]