# How to plot a piecewise function in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

So when I try to plot my function I get some errors and nothing shows up. Some sort of Package PGF Math error an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill formatted floating point number whatever that means.

my code is

```
\begin{align*}
    \int_{-2}^{3}\frac{x+15}{64}dx+\int_{0}^{3}\frac{3}{4}+kxdx=1\\
    \frac{7}{16}+\left[\frac{3}{4}x+k\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{3}=1\\
    \frac{9}{8}+\frac{9k}{2}=\frac{9}{16}
    k=-\frac{1}{8}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x >= -2, \x < 0) * (\x/64+15/64) +
              and(\x >= 0, \x < 3) * (3/8-\x/8)     +
              (\x >= 3) * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

\addplot [blue,thick] {func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It is helpful to give your entire code, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. In particular, knowing the packages you are using provides important information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conveniently plot a list of various transformed functions y=a|f(b|x+c|)|+d of a piecewisely-defined fundamental function y=f(x)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611020/how-to-conveniently-plot-a-list-of-various-transformed-functions-y-afbxc)